# what is causing borders to appear in my modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

there are 2 silver borders in my modal, I looked over the css but there are no border property or anything of that sort that could be the cause. I tried going through developer tools to try and maybe select the border but realized I am unable to do that too. I tried going through the code individually but couldn't locate the source

I looked over the entire code and I feel dumb but I couldn't figure out what's causing the border to appear for the life of me.

[image]

my JSX:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import "./Signin.css";

const Modal = props => {
  const closeOnEscapeKeyDown = e => {
    if ((e.charCode || e.keyCode) === 27) {
      props.closeModal();
    }
    if ((e.charCode || e.keyCode) === 87) {
        props.showModal();
      }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", closeOnEscapeKeyDown);
    return function cleanup() {
      document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", closeOnEscapeKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <CSSTransition
      in={props.show}
      unmountOnExit
      timeout={{ enter: 0, exit: 300 }}
    >
      <div className="modal" onClick={props.closeModal}>
        <div className="modal-content" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h4 className="modal-title">Sign in</h4>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">
              <div className = "modal-input-field">
                <div className = "modal-username-field">
                    <p className = "p-username">Username</p>
                    <input tag = "username" placeholder = "eg: muhammet-aldulaimi"/> 
                </div>
                <div className = "modal-password-field">
                    <p className = "p-password">Password</p>
                    <input tag = "password" placeholder = "eg: someStrongPassword123"/> 
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className = "modal-submit"> 
                <button className = "modal-submit-button">Submit</button>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <button onClick={props.closeModal} className="button">
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </CSSTransition>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

my CSS:

```
    .modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  .modal.enter-done {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: visible;
  }
  
  .modal.exit {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .modal-content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url(../../Images/flowersSidebarBackground.png);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transform: translateY(-200px);
  }
  
  .modal.enter-done .modal-content {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  .modal.exit .modal-content {
    transform: translateY(-200px);
  }
  
  .modal-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  }

  .modal-title {
    /* padding-bottom: 20px; */
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;

    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #a9dba4, #e25734);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-clip: text;
    
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 40px;
  }
  
  .modal-body {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .modal-input-field {
      width: 80%;
  }

  .modal-username-field {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .p-username {
      padding-top: 10px;
      font-size: 20px;

      background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #a9dba4, #e25734);
      background-size: 100%;
      background-repeat: repeat;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
      -moz-background-clip: text;
      -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
      background-clip: text;
  }

  .modal-password-field {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .p-password {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #a9dba4, #e25734);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-clip: text;

}
  .modal-submit {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      padding-top: 30px;
  }

  .modal-submit-button {
    background-color: rgb(24, 102, 116);
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border-radius: 7px;

  }

  .modal-footer {
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: have you looked at the browser developer tools?

Comment: I have as I stated previously. Couldn't click on the border to locate the source.

Comment: Could you please create a working example on codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-shadow-wkxi0?file=/public/index.html:1097-1347
By uploading a sandbox version I have traced the issue to a bootstrap cdn that is somehow conflicting with the modal's css. What is the best way to remove the border effect that it is causing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by tracing the problem to a Bootstrap cdn, I fixed removing the borders by adding a `border: 0px solid black`  to make the border 0 pixels therefor nonexistent+

Answer (score 1):

The borders give you visual feedback that the element is focused. You can get rid of it by adding the following code in your Modal.css

```
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```